# How do I create a Set method for a class with a variable-dimension container?

Tags: python, multidimensional-array, set

If I have a list class that can be initialized with a variable number of dimensions, how do I set an entry at the lowest level of the list with an element? (Also would like to know if my get method should work in theory)

I'm trying to simulate board games that use multiple dimensions (Can you even imagine 5-th dimensional chess? How about 17th?)

```
class Board():
    DIMENSIONS = [8, 8]

    #board and pieces have their respective rules.

    def __init__(self, D=[8,8]):
        if len(D) <= 0:
            board = [None for i in range(D)]
        else:
            board = [None for i in range(D[0])]
            for j in range(1,len(D)):
                board = [board for i in range(D[j])]

    def get(self, location):
        try:
            for coordinate in location:
                result = board[coordinate]
            return result
        except:
            print('Error: Cannot get coordinate')
            return None

    def set(self, location, piece):
        try:
            for coordinate in location:
                result = self.board[coordinate]
            result = piece
        except:
            print('Error: Cannot set coordinate')

    def move(self, start, end):
        x = self.get(start)
        if x is not None:
            for m, r in x.moves, x.rules:
                if self.get(is_legitimate(self, start, m, r)) == end:
                    = x
                    pass
            #Check alignment and position, if it's transformable react according to board rules.

    #returns false if not, but returns location if legit.
    def is_legitimate(self, start, move, rule):
        location = start
        forwardback = True
        while move != 1:
            primes = [2]
            while move % primes[-1] == 0:
                if forwardback:
                    location[len(primes) // 2]+=1
                else:
                    location[len(primes) // 2]-=1
                move = move % primes[-1]
                if not self.bounds(location):
                    return False
            primes.append(next_prime(primes))
            forwardback = not forwardback


    def bounds(self, location):
        for coordinate, d in location, self.DIMENSIONS:
            if coordinate < 0 or coordinate > d:
                return False
        return True
#using prime numbers?        


def next_prime(primes):
    if len(primes) == 0:
        return 2
    prev_result = 1
    result = 2
    while prev_result != result:
        prev_result = result
        for x in primes:
            if result == x or result % x == 0:
                result += 1
                break
    return result
```

Code is mostly rough draft, don't play just look.

Comment: Use ```numpy``` library. You can represent a N-dimensional array with ```numpy.ndarray``` easily.

Comment: Sorry, I meant with the array, how do I set elements when the number of dimensions is variable? like x[1][7][3] but with potentially infinite []s?

Comment: Like put but with a set of directions. So say I chose to make the board x-dimensions. How do I get and put individual stuff, like chess pieces from a class, into it?

Comment: ```ndarray``` supports integer indexation. Use 1 index per dimension. You can add a new axis whenever you need

Comment: Say I have an argument called (directions). directions is a list containing indexes. how do I plug directions into the ndarray (board) so that I can change the board's individual elements, replacing items (like chess pieces) from one index to another?